# NUL values in the first character in receive function of sockets in c++ while sending data from android client

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets, winsock

I need  to transfer data from android client to c++ server using sockets and using this code.

I am sending "ACK" from Android client and reeving NUL pointer in the Server C++ and then the" ACK". 
Receiving message[512] is representing like this:

Data :

```
messageString[0]= NUL
messageString[1]= A; 
messageString[2]= C; 
messageString[3]= K;
```

ACIII Values :

```
messageString[0]= 0 
messageString[1]= 65; 
messageString[2]= 67; 
messageString[3]= 75;
```

Why am i receiving NUL in the receive in the c++ side.

As i am debugging and have realized that when i receive a message second time it is coming correct. But for the first time NUL is there for every new type of message.

Error Image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Oz1-JlgLdTVVR6UUc4TGZtU2s/view?pli=1

Receive function on C++ server:

```
char messageString[512];
int result = recv(socket, messageString, strlen(messageString), 0);
```

Send in Andorid client :

```
public class AgentOutputChannel
{
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    OutputStream socketOutputStream = null;

    static  AgentOutputChannel outputChannel = null;

    private AgentOutputChannel()
    {       

    }

    private AgentOutputChannel(Socket socket, OutputStream outStream)
    {
        clientSocket = socket;
        socketOutputStream = outStream;
    }

    public  static AgentOutputChannel GetOutputChannel(Socket socket, OutputStream outStream)
    {
        if(outputChannel == null)
        {
            outputChannel = new AgentOutputChannel(socket, outStream);
        }
        return outputChannel;
    }

    public void Send(byte[] message)
    {
        try 
        {
            if(!clientSocket.isOutputShutdown())
            {
                socketOutputStream.write(message);
            }
            else
            {
                outputChannel = null;
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Why am i receiving NUL in the receive in the c++ side.`. Where are you receiving that? Which variable is NUL? We cannot see in the Android code what you send. Please show how you build up the message.

Comment: "ACK".getBytes() i am passing this like Send("ACK".getBytes());

Comment: Error Image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Oz1-JlgLdTVVR6UUc4TGZtU2s/view?pli=1

Comment: What do `messageString[0]= ` and 'ACII' mean? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I have shared an image in the post. You can see what i was saying. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Oz1-JlgLdTVVR6UUc4TGZtU2s/view?pli=1

Comment: I read what you wrote. It's meaningless. Please clarify. In your post. Here. Not in some bozo third-party site that might disappear tomorrow. Questions asked here must be completely self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int result = recv(socket, messageString, strlen(messageString), 0);
```

should instead read

```
int result = recv(socket, messageString, sizeof(messageString), 0);
```

Also try printing the values of each byte of message right before

```
socketOutputStream.write(message);
```

to make sure that you aren't transmitting the null, ACK

Comment: Android client is  not transmitting  any null , but i am receiving it on c++ server side.

Comment: Please react to the use of `sizeof`. You should use it. And if the Android client is not transmitting any null then what are `messageString[0]=  ` and `messageString[0]=  0`? And what are rhose `<br>'s?

Comment: <br> was typo and edited from the post. Using size of but also same result. I  am just transmitting the "ACK".getBytes() from android and i am receiving null at first array node. I have given the messageString[0] in ASCII and data when i am debugging and keep a watch.

Comment: As i am debugging and have realized that when i receive a message second time it is coming correct. But for the first time NUL is there for every new type of message.

Comment: Error Image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Oz1-JlgLdTVVR6UUc4TGZtU2s/view?pli=1

Comment: There are errors which cannot be seen in the code posted on stackoverflow.com  For instance recv may return a count less then sizeof(messageString) but still have bytes left to read.  Also, what if recv isn't returning any data at all but errno is EAGAIN?  Add a memset( messageString, 'x', sizeof( messageString ) ) before your recv to make sure the contents are being updated at all.

Comment: i am sending ACK 3 bytes and receving 4 bytes ACK with NUL in start. And i have checked the error and nothing is being thrown.

Comment: Did you actually print out the return value of recv to make sure it is "4"?  Or do you assume this because you see 0,A,C,K in the debugger?